# Shared dockerfiles layers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have 3 services that should run from the same codebase but they run in different containers in production. I want to create one Dockerfile with the same "build" layer with the necessary commands and tools to run the services and create each service a Dockerfile with the extended "build" layer. I read about the multistage layer but I saw examples only in the same file so it still makes my code decoupled.

Do you have any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: If your code base Is same why multi stage? Same dockerfile with different CMD will work. Override CMD at run time to run different process

Comment: @Adiii it's ok for now, but if I want just to extend that layer and add different commands to each service layer how you suggest to do it?

Comment: You can use four separate Dockerfiles (one for the base and then three that start `FROM` it), or have one image but override the `CMD` at run time.  If you want multiple images out you can't avoid running `docker build` multiple times.